# If point is nothing how come line which made up of set of points has length

Tags: geometry

As per wiki , In particular, the geometric points do not have any length, area, volume, or any other dimensional attribute.But when line is made up of set of points how come it has length? I am not too good in maths but this question was back in my mind since many days. Someone please clear things up. Thanks.